# How to check how many users have updated to new version in Google Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Is there any way or any section in Google Analytics that I can check how many users have updated their android app to the latest version?

Comment: Are you posting a version string anywhere?

Comment: Your app has its version on its manifest. Can't you just use that?

Answer (score 0):

You see in [the best practices for Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087?hl=en) that different app versions are already tracked (most likely as long as you release them via Google Play Store).

Comment: Link broken. Please describe your answer without relying on a link.